# Failover in SQL Server 2017 with Availibility Group

Tags: sql-server-2017, availability-group

I'm configuring a failover in an above-mentioned setup with two nodes and synchronous commit. It's a test setup. Primary is server1 and secondary is server2. I configured the availability group and added the database.
When I manually execute a failover it seems to work, server2 becomes primary, but when I connect to cluster resource IP, the database remains in a read-only mode. It works only when I shutdown server1. So far I couldn't find any solution.